# Foundation go to Orbit first slide

Tags: html, css, orbit

I have an Orbit slider inside a Reveal modal.

I want to reset the slider to go to the first slide when closing the modal.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).on('opened', '[data-reveal]', function () {
      // Callback triggered when reveal modal is closed
      $(this).find("[data-orbit-slide=0]").click(); // Click the link to first slide in orbit modal
    });
```

When slider is closed (and invisible) interactions don't seem to work reliably. Hence we operate once the modal is visible.

Comment: It doesn't work. Here goo.gl/Zv8oAQ when you click the first thumbnail in the carousel it opens a Reveal with an Orbit slider. Change the slide then close the Reveal, then open it again, doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: OK bullets have been removed through configuration option { bullets: false }. My code assumed the default configuration where bullets are visible.

Comment: Ok, I have put the bullets back. It has a strange behavior now. Note that I have put 2 Orbits, 1 in each Reveal.

Answer (score 0):

Foundation press has changed some verbiage since the previous answer. You can also use:

```
$(document).find("[data-slide=0]").click();
```